# How to add an external Library in C

Tags: c, macos, visual-studio-code

Hello guys I am in a big problem I need to use an external library but I don't know how to add it. The library is Serd library.

I am programming in Visual Studio Code for Mac.

This is the link for download the library : https://gitlab.com/drobilla/serd

Thank you very much.

I expect to found how to add an external library in C

Comment: https://gitlab.com/drobilla/serd/-/blob/master/INSTALL.md, or if you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, `brew install serd`

Answer (score 0):

If you have [homebrew](https://brew.sh) installed, there is a `serd` [formula](https://formulae.brew.sh/formula/serd), and you can install it with `brew install serd`.

Alternatively, you can compile and install from source. The instructions are available in the project's `INSTALL.md` file [on gitlab](https://gitlab.com/drobilla/serd/-/blob/master/INSTALL.md).